# How to make a Header that Animates from transparent to solid on Scrolling UP in React-Native

Tags: react-native, mobile

Im trying to animate a header that goes from transparent to solid color when scroll content up in ReactNative. I've already see other's examples, but all of them, always show react navigation or scroll down . . . I appreciate any help.

When i open the app:
[first screen of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abJO8.png)

Then, when i scroll content up, i want to header and statusbar black.
[when scroll content, header and statusbar must be solid black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r70Kt.png)

UPDATE!
My code so far:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, Fragment } from "react";
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ImageBackground,
  StatusBar,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
} from "react-native";
import { COLORS, FONTS, SIZES, icons, images } from "../constants";

const Home = () => {
const [destaque, setDestaque] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
 fetch("https://myr3po.fake.com/static/list-destaque.json")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => setDestaque(json[0]))
  .catch((error) => console.error(error))
  .finally(() => setLoading(false));
}, []);

function renderHeader() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <ImageBackground
        source={{
          uri: destaque.image_capa,
          cache: "default",
        }}
        resizeMode="cover"
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          top: 0,
          right: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          left: 0,
        }}
      />
      <View
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          top: 0,
          right: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          left: 0,
          backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)",
        }}
      ></View>

      <View
        style={{
          flex: 5,
          paddingTop: SIZES.padding2,
          alignItems: "center",
          height: 400,
        }}
      ></View>
      <View
        style={{ flex: 1.8, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}
      ></View>

      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: "row",
          paddingVertical: 20,
          margin: SIZES.padding,
          borderRadius: SIZES.radius,
          backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)",
        }}
      >
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center" }}
          onPress={() =>
            navigation.navigate("ComicDetail", {
              comic: destaque,
            })
          }
        >
        <Text style={{ ...FONTS.h2, color: COLORS.white }}>
          {destaque.title}
        </Text>
        <Text style={{ ...FONTS.h3, color: COLORS.white }}>Ler agora</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  </View>
);
}

return (
<Fragment>
  <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 0, backgroundColor: "black" }} />

  <StatusBar
    barStyle="light-content"
    backgroundColor="#000"
    networkActivityIndicatorVisible={true}
  />

  <View
    style={{
      flexDirection: "row",
      justifyContent: "center",
      alignItems: "center",
      paddingHorizontal: 16,
      paddingVertical: 10,
      backgroundColor: "#000",
    }}
  >
    <Image
      source={require("../assets/dc-logo.png")}
      style={{ width: 192, height: 30 }}
    />
  </View>
  <ScrollView>
    {renderHeader()}
    <Text>hi</Text>
    <Text>hi</Text>
    <Text>hi</Text>
    <Text>hi</Text>
    <Text>hi</Text>
  </ScrollView>
</Fragment>
);
};

export default Home;
```

What i really want is, screen shows main image with transparent header, only with logo (without background), and, when the screen scroll up, the statusbar and header becomes background black.

When scroll up, i want to show this:
[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZIyy.jpg)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share the code you are using, and describe exactly how it is not working?

Comment: I just updated with the code. Thanks!